# Is there a way to keep dot segments in url using Uri class?

Tags: c#, uri

When I create a uri with dot segments:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost/../../g");
```

The uri class removes the `../` segments and the result uri becomes:

```
http://localhost/g
```

When there is a path before the dots:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost/a/b/c/./../../g");
// Result: http://localhost/a/g
```

Looks like the `Uri` class is following [the standart](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) (Page 33 - remove_dot_segments), but is there any way to keep dot segments instead of automatically resolving the target uri, using [Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) class? Or do I need a custom implementation?

Comment: You could use `uri.OriginalString`

Comment: @KSib OriginalString doesn't matter when sending a request. AbsoluteUri matters

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTTP then no, it will always escape them if you use the Uri class.  It escapes for all of the following: `file, http, https, net.pipe, and net.tcp`

If you are using something like `ftp` then it won't escape, but it sounds like that isn't an option for you.

From [MSDN's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx):

> As part of canonicalization in the constructor for some schemes,
>   escaped representations are compacted. The schemes for which URI will
>   compact escaped sequences include the following: file, http, https,
>   net.pipe, and net.tcp. **For all other schemes, escaped sequences are
>   not compacted**. For example: if you percent encode the two dots ".." as
>   "%2E%2E" then the URI constructor will compact this sequence for some
>   schemes. For example, the following code sample shows a URI
>   constructor for the http scheme.

Comment: that's unfortunate. do you know of any 3rd party library that does what I want?

Comment: Hrrm possibly, what exactly is it that you want to do?  If you want to return a `Uri` object for a `http://...` Uri that has dots in it I think you are out of luck.  If you just want a string representation I'm sure you could work something out.

Comment: I would like to keep dots, and then create a request to that exact url, so I'm guessing I won't just need a custom uri implementation cause WebRequest class is following the same standarts.

Comment: It looks like the `WebRequest` constructor takes a string for the URL to hit.  Seems like you could just skip using the `Uri` class and pass in the string you want to target, correct?

Comment: Ahh, I was wondering if it uses the `Uri` class behind the scenes.